# Is there a Delete option on the mobile app?

Tags: support

Every once in awhile, we get a post where the author decided to delete it.  But instead of actually deleting, they just write "Deleted" in the body.  Another one showed up today ([Backup new Windows 8.1 system after upgrading from Windows 8](https://superuser.com/a/1113769/364367)), an answer with no votes, and when I suggested that they just click the delete option, they said they were on the mobile app and couldn't find such an option.  I'm not familiar with the mobile app, but they posted a screenshot, and there was no obvious delete option.

Is there a way to delete your own post on the mobile app?

Comment: If they have an upvoted answer then they may not be able to delete it.  Link to the question in question?

Comment: I think this should be on Meta.SE...?

Comment: It's a feature, not a bug: [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app)

Comment: @Mokubai, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked the Android app and there is no delete button, not even for my own non-accepted answers. As linked by Mokubai in the comments, [it's an intentional decision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246899/295684).